# How to pass the name of dataframe inside a list to sqldf?

Tags: r, sqldf

I am annotating several data frames by using sqldf package.
The annotation data is in a dataframe **annot**.
I use **INNER JOIN** to select the corresponding information by **id** value

To automate the process, I write the code below:

```
prepareAnnot <- function(x){  
annoted <- sqldf("SELECT x.*, 
annot.* 
FROM x INNER JOIN annot 
ON x.id = annot.id;")

return(annoted)}
```

I put 5 data frames (A,B,C,D,E) into a list and want to apply the prepareAnnot function 
and save the annotated data in a new data frame with suffix "anotated"

```
myresults <- list(A=A,B=B,C=C,D=D,E=E)

for (i in seq_along(myresults)){
assign (paste(names(myresults)[i],"annotated",sep="_"),prepareAnnot(myresults[i]))
}
```

However it seems the prepareAnnot function can not recognize the dataframe name in my list.
and I got the error message below:

```
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such table: x)
```

How should I correctly pass the data frame name inside the list to the function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot replicate your error. Also, it's not a good idea to use `assign()` like that. If you have a bunch of variables that are related, it's better just to keep them in a list so that you can run vectorized operations over them easily. Here's a working example

```
annot <- data.frame(id=1:10, n=letters[1:10])
prepareAnnot <- function(x) {
    sqldf("select x.*, annot.n from x INNER JOIN annot ON x.id = annot.id")
}

myresults <- list(A=data.frame(id=1:3), B=data.frame(id=4:7))    
annotated <- lapply(myresults, prepareAnnot)
annotated
```

tested with "sqldf_0.4-7.1".

I can get that same error if one of the elements in `myresults` is not a data.frame. Be sure to check

```
sapply(myresults, class)
```

to see that they are all proper data.frames.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Flick ! Your solution works, I should use lapply function.